# Multiple distros: extremely slow window rendering, with whole display blanking momentarily

Tags: display, radeon

#### Symptom

When an application window is rewritten due to any change in content, rendering takes an unusually long time (many seconds for what is normally instantaneous), and the entire display goes blank momentarily before the new content is displayed.

***Details***

For any activity involving multiple window modifications, like scrolling any window, or a browser loading a complex web page, the problem repeats with each incremental change until final rendering is complete.  This results in the computer freezing, sometimes for minutes. with the display going on and off every few seconds with each incremental screen write, making it unusable.

When I encounter the problem, it is with a new Linux OS doing nothing demanding.  The activity is typically OS setup on a fresh install or live session, with a single, low-demand utility open; or a couple, like a terminal plus a configuration utility.  Occasionally, it will include the bundled barebones browser (no add-ons), with one or two reference tabs open.  Each open application compounds the problem.  Switching from one open application window to another can take several minutes.

#### Particulars

***System:***  The computer is an old Gateway desktop; off-the-shelf OEM hardware:

- Quad Core AMD Phenom II X4 805 CPU
- ATI Radeon HD 3200 graphics
- 8 GB RAM

It has multi-boot original OEM Windows 7 plus a number of Linux distros (Ubuntu and Mint), which all run on it routinely with no problems.  I occasionally boot other Linux distros from a USB drive, with no issues.

There's no evidence of any malfunctioning hardware or symptoms of any problem with those OSes.

***History & Scope:***

- Many months ago, I installed Gecko Linux (a spin of openSUSE) with the Cinnamon desktop.  That distro was installed on several other computers and worked properly.  On this PC, it exhibited the symptoms described above.

  Actual openSUSE with some other desktop environments (Cinnamon wasn't offered), had no problem on this PC.  I eventually gave up trying to solve it and just installed a different distro (Mint Cinnamon), which worked fine.
- I later tried MX Linux (Debian stable + Xfce) v18.1.  Again, that worked on other computers (both AMD and Intel hardware), but had the same problem on this computer.  It wasn't the only game in town, so I just used a different distro.
- MX recently came out with v19, which I  installed and successfully use on other computers.  On this computer, it still has the symptom.  I installed Mint Xfce and it works fine, as did several other Xfce-based distros.

I have MX v19 as the default distro on several other computers and like it, so I'm trying to solve whatever is the underlying problem on what I'm using as my main computer.

#### Resolution attempts

- Logically, it seems like it has to be some compatibility issue with the Radeon graphics hardware, because that is the only unique thing about this computer that relates to display output.  The symptoms occur whether the distro is run from a live DVD session or installed on a drive.  The problem distros work without a hitch on other hardware.  Other distros with the same desktop environments work fine on this computer.
- All of the distros (both working and problematic ones) use the open source Radeon driver, so the driver is not the issue.

  Certain older Radeon graphics cards can have some difficulties with the open source driver (although I didn't find this specific issue previously mentioned).  There used to be a proprietary driver (fglrx), that was sometimes helpful, but that appears to be deprecated; it is no longer available through the Debian backports (MX 19 is based on Buster).  I tried the proprietary driver from the AMD website, but it hasn't been updated since the dawn of time, and had no effect.
- Cinnamon and Xfce use different window managers.  Different distros use the DE's default window manager for Cinnamon or for Xfce, so the WM doesn't seem to be the issue.
- MX has compositing disabled, so it isn't that.
- The problem appears to be limited to certain distros on this particular hardware.  I couldn't find reports of similar problems in general by other users of the two distros in question.  The hardware is fairly old, so problem reports based on the hardware aren't expected.
- Based on @linux-fan's input in the comments, I tried getting some diagnostic information (some detail has been incorporated above).  This turned out to be generally difficult and slow because collecting diagnostics tends to freeze the system due to screen activity.

  I no longer have openSUSE, but still had live-DVDs for Gecko with Cinnamon, Xfce, Mate, and Plasma (only Cinnamon had been previously tested on this PC), and MX v18.1 and 19.  I compared those with some working distros.

  All four of the Gecko distros had the symptom, so the issue is with the distro, itself, not the DE.

  There was nothing of significance in the Xorg.0.log files, and no system error logs were generated.

  A few different versions of the X.org server were represented, but both working and problematic distros shared the same versions, and the newest version was on a problematic distro.

  `top` showed no serious CPU or memory usage.  However, it is a real-time display.  When the screen blanked, that display disappeared and there was no unusual activity when the display resumed.  So it produced no information at the height of the symptom.
- MX v19 is built on Debian Buster Xfce.  I installed the Debian "source" and that did not suffer from this symptom.  I tried comparing the lists of installed packages.  There are nearly 4,000 package differences, many of which are dependencies.  There are also endless differences in settings.  This comparison approach isn't practical for identifying the problem.

#### Question

Is this symptom diagnostic of a specific known problem or subsystem?  Are there diagnostics I could run that would shed some light?

Comment: Interesting diagnostics: Run `top` (or something more advanced like `atop`) to see if there is any slow software-rendering going on. Check `Xorg.0.log` files for errors and differences in drivers loaded on the good and "slow" systems.

Comment: @linux-fan, thanks.  I'll check and update.